# unexpected T_ELSE in C:\AppServ\www\sueldoo.php on line 9

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in C:\AppServ\www\sueldoo.php on line 9

```
<?php
$sueldo=3000;
$aumento;
$total;
if($sueldo<3000)
$aumento=$sueldo*0.25;
$total=$sueldo+$aumento;
echo"El sueldo del trabajador es de $ $sueldo, por lo <br> tanto recibira un aumento de %25 con un sueldo total de $ $total";
else
if($sueldo>=3000 && $sueldo<=5500)
$aumento=$sueldo*0.21;
$total=$sueldo+$aumento;
echo"El sueldo del trabajador es de $ $sueldo, por lo <br> tanto recibira un aumento de %21 con un sueldo total de $$total";
elseif($sueldo>5500)
$aumento=$sueldo*0.18;
$total=$sueldo+$aumento;
echo"El sueldo del trabajador es de $ $sueldo, por lo <br> tanto recibira un aumento de %18 con un sueldo total de $$total";
?>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué omites el uso de llaves para identificar los bloques de ejecución?

Comment: pues eso, tienes unas estructuras de control sin llaves `{ }` y no se entiende bien qué esperas obtener con los else tres y cuatro líneas después.

Comment: Te falta un espacio después de echo: `echo "`, con eso *"compilará"*. Los bloques es otro problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que no usas una estructura válida para los condicionales (PHP no es Python).

De forma regular (mas no exclusiva) deberías tener algo como:

```
<?php

$sueldo=3000;
$aumento;
$total;
    if ($sueldo<3000) {
        $aumento=$sueldo*0.25;
        $total=$sueldo+$aumento;
        echo"El sueldo del trabajador es de $ $sueldo, por lo <br> tanto recibira un aumento de %25 con un sueldo total de $ $total";        
    } elseif($sueldo>=3000 && $sueldo<=5500) {
        $aumento=$sueldo*0.21;
        $total=$sueldo+$aumento;
        echo"El sueldo del trabajador es de $ $sueldo, por lo <br> tanto recibira un aumento de %21 con un sueldo total de $$total";        
    } elseif($sueldo>5500) {
        $aumento=$sueldo*0.18;
        $total=$sueldo+$aumento;
        echo"El sueldo del trabajador es de $ $sueldo, por lo <br> tanto recibira un aumento de %18 con un sueldo total de $$total";        
    }
```

Por otro lado si vas a omitir el uso de las llaves, entonces debes apegarte a una [sintaxis válida de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php#control-structures.elseif) donde las llaves que identifican los bloques de código a ejecutar se sustituyen con **`:`**  y terminando el bloque de condicionales con **`endif;`**

Quedando de esta manera:

```
<?php

$sueldo=3000;
$aumento;
$total;
    if($sueldo<3000):
        $aumento=$sueldo*0.25;
        $total=$sueldo+$aumento;
        echo"El sueldo del trabajador es de $ $sueldo, por lo <br> tanto recibira un aumento de %25 con un sueldo total de $ $total";
    elseif($sueldo>=3000 && $sueldo<=5500):
        $aumento=$sueldo*0.21;
        $total=$sueldo+$aumento;
        echo"El sueldo del trabajador es de $ $sueldo, por lo <br> tanto recibira un aumento de %21 con un sueldo total de $$total";
    elseif($sueldo>5500):
        $aumento=$sueldo*0.18;
        $total=$sueldo+$aumento;
        echo"El sueldo del trabajador es de $ $sueldo, por lo <br> tanto recibira un aumento de %18 con un sueldo total de $$total";
    endif;
```

Como notas en ambos casos, la sintaxis importa.

Por otro lado y ajeno al error que motivó la pregunta yo creo que tu último `elseif` esta demás desde el momento que estás tratando de establecer que todo sueldo que sea mayor a 5500 recibirá un 18% de aumento entonces yo lo quitaría por que ya estableciste para cuando sea menor, para cuando sea mayor o igual y menor o igual a determinada cantidad, entonces todo sueldo que no *caiga* en esas condiciones quedará en el `else`

Quedando así:

```
<?php

$sueldo=3000;
$aumento;
$total;
    if($sueldo<3000):
        /*
            Aquí tus acciones
        */
     elseif($sueldo>=3000 && $sueldo<=5500):
        /*
            Aquí tus otras acciones
        */
    else:
        /*
            Aquí tus acciones default
        */
    endif;
```